# I want to make springy effect for ball

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I have staticbody and dynamicbody with box2d in cocos2d. dynamicbody is ball. I want to make springy like a spring. like this example : [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=TK27I0U4TRU&noredirect=1)
thanks. please help

**Normal**
 [image]

**Anormal**
[image]

**Very Anormal**

[image]

please Help. Why? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate soft body with box2d using soft distance joints: arrange bodies along the contour of your desired shape, connect them with joints, draw texture over vertices defined by positions of the bodies. You can find tutorial [here](http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/03/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-14/).